# Z3 cannot check equivalence of two formulae

Tags: python, z3, z3py, quantifiers, first-order-logic

(Why are not the math formulae showing correctly?)

I am performing a test over the Z3 library in Python (Collab) to see whether it knows to distinguish formulae.

The test is the following: (1) I make a quantifier elimination over a formula $phi_1$, (2) I change the formula in a way it remains semantically equivalent: for instance, $phi_1 \equiv (a<b+1)$ to $\phi_2 \equiv (a<1+b)$, (3) I test whether $phi_1=phi_2$.

To see whether $phi_1=phi_2$, I perform the following query: for all the variables, I see whether formulae imply each other. Like $\forall * . (\phi_1 \rightleftarrow \phi_2)$ Is this correct?

So, imagine I apply this on my machine:

```
x, t1, t2 = Reals('x t1 t2')
g = Goal()
g.add(Exists(x, And(t1 < x, x < t2)))
t = Tactic('qe')
res = t(g)
```

The result `res` is `[[Not(0 <= t1 + -1*t2)]]`, so a semantically equivalent formula is: `[[Not(0 <= -1*t2 + t1)]]` Am I right?

Let us check whether `[[Not(0 <= t1 + -1*t2)]] = [[Not(0 <= -1*t2 + t1)]]`. So I apply the universal double-implication formula above:

```
w = Goal()
w.add(ForAll(t1, (ForAll(t2, And(
                                  Implies(Not(0 <= -1*t2 + t1), Not(0 <= t1 + -1*t2)),
                                  Implies(Not(0 <= t1 + -1*t2), Not(0 <= -1*t2 + t1)),                   
                        )))))
tt = Tactic('qe')
areThey = tt(w)
print (areThey)
```

And the result is.. `[[]]` I do not know how to interpret this. An optimistic approach is to think that it returns emptyness, since quantifier elimination has been capable to eliminate both quantifiers successfully (i.e. with **true** result).

I think this can be a problem of using a wrong tactic, or maybe Z3 does not deal OK with universal quantifiers.

However, the most probable situation is that I am probably missing something key and Z3 **is** clever enough to distinguish.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just means that the quantifier-elimination tactic reduced the goal to empty-subset; i.e., it eliminated it completely. You've nothing left to do.

In general, to check if two formulas are equivalent in z3, you assert the negation of their equivalence; and see if z3 can come up with a model: If the negation is satisfiable, then that is a counter-example for the original equivalence. If you get `unsat`, then you conclude that the original equivalence holds for all inputs. This is how you code that in z3:

```py
from z3 import *

t1, t2 = Reals('t1 t2')

s = Solver()
fml1 = Not(0 <= -1*t2 + t1)
fml2 = Not(0 <= t1 + -1*t2)
s.add(Not(fml1 == fml2))
print(s.check())
```

If you run this, you'll see:

```
unsat
```

meaning the equivalence holds.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answers my question! In any case, was my reasoning correct? I mean the forall * double-implication.

Comment: z3 is an SMT solver: That is it'll try to find a model for the formula. This is why you have to negate it. So, you'd have something like `Not(ForAll([t1, t2]. fml1 == fml2))`. (Notice that bi-implication over booleans is simply equality; so you can simplify that part.) Now, if you push the negation inside, you'll see that you get: `Exists([t1, t2]. Not(fml1 == fml2))`. But a top-level declaration is equivalent to an existential, so you end up with the program I gave. To summarize, your double-implication needs a negation on top, and you can simplify by using equality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! A last question: is that grouping ```ForAll([t1, t2]..)``` correct in the Z3 syntax? In case not, is there a way to do it? I mean writing ```ForAll([t1,t2]...) ``` instead of ```ForAll(t1(ForAll t2...)```.

Comment: It should mean the same thing. i.e., you can group it, or stagger it without any difference.

Comment: Yep, I know they mean the same semantically, but perhaps z3 did not allow, syntax-wise, to group quantified variables under the same quantifier. Anyway I have tested it and does work!

Comment: yes, both are allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, any link to 'invite for a coffee'? I have seen this way of being grateful in some posts at Stack :))

Comment: I'm not aware of any "coffee" options on stack-overflow; though that'd be cool indeed :-) Z3 stack-overflow is a small enough community that everyone tries to help each other.